# Importing JSON file in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

I have a `JSON` file that looks like following:

```
{

  "primaryBright":    "#2DC6FB",
  "primaryMain":      "#05B4F0",
  "primaryDarker":    "#04A1D7",
  "primaryDarkest":   "#048FBE",

  "secondaryBright":  "#4CD2C0",
  "secondaryMain":    "#00BFA5",
  "secondaryDarker":  "#009884",
  "secondaryDarkest": "#007F6E",

  "tertiaryMain":     "#FA555A",
  "tertiaryDarker":   "#F93C42",
  "tertiaryDarkest":  "#F9232A",

  "darkGrey":         "#333333",
  "lightGrey":        "#777777"
}
```

I'm trying to import it into a `.tsx` file. For this I added this to the type definition:

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

And I'm importing it like this.

`import colors = require('../colors.json')`

And in the file, I use the color `primaryMain` as `colors.primaryMain`. However I get an error:

> Property 'primaryMain' does not exist on type 'typeof "*.json"

Comment: Your module declaration and your import form disagree.

Comment: Do you mind showing an example? I'm typescript noob.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript compiler error when importing json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950966/typescript-compiler-error-when-importing-json-file)

Answer (score 216, accepted):

The import form and the module declaration need to agree about the shape of the module, about what it exports.

When you write (a suboptimal practice for importing JSON since TypeScript 2.9 when targeting compatible module formats<sup>**see note**</sup>)

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

You are stating that all modules that have a specifier ending in `.json` have a single export *named* `default`.

There are several ways you can correctly consume such a module including

```
import a from "a.json";
a.primaryMain
```

and

```
import * as a from "a.json";
a.default.primaryMain
```

and

```
import {default as a} from "a.json";
a.primaryMain
```

and

```
import a = require("a.json");
a.default.primaryMain
```

The first form is the best and the syntactic sugar it leverages is the very reason JavaScript has `default` exports.

However I mentioned the other forms to give you a hint about what's going wrong. Pay special attention to the last one. `require` gives you an object representing the module itself and *not* its exported bindings.

So why the error? Because you wrote

```
import a = require("a.json");
a.primaryMain
```

And yet there is no export named `primaryMain` declared by your `"*.json"`.

All of this assumes that your module loader is providing the JSON as the `default` export as suggested by your original declaration.

**Note:** Since TypeScript 2.9, you can use the [`--resolveJsonModule` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html) to have TypeScript analyze imported `.json` files and provide correct information regarding their shape obviating the need for a wildcard module declaration and validating the presence of the file. This is not supported for certain target module formats.

Comment: @Royi that depends on your loader. For remote files consider using `await import('remotepath');`

Comment: @jbmusso I added some information regarding the improvements introduced by later versions of TypeScript but I don't think this answer is out of date because it is conceptual. However, I'm open to suggestions for further improvements.

Comment: The risk is that some people could simply copy/paste the first lines of your answer, only fixing the symptom and not the root cause. I believe @kentor's answer yields greater details and provides a more complete answer. A recommendation would be to move your Note on top of your answer, clearly stating that this is the correct way to tackle this issue as of today.

Comment: `import {default as yourPreferredName} from "any.json";`
works like a charm

Comment: @Cyclion `import {default as yourPreferredName} from "any.json";` is proper but it's usually preferable to write `import yourPreferredName from "any.json";` which has precisely the same meaning.

Comment: @kentor's solution is great if you want type checking on your json files, but that could come with a TS compilation/type-checking performance cost. Using `declare module "*.json"` listed here is great if you want to import json files without type checking them (boosting TS analysis performance).

Answer (score 833):

With TypeScript 2.9.+ you can simply import JSON files with benefits like typesafety and intellisense by doing this:

```
import colorsJson from '../colors.json'; // This import style requires "esModuleInterop", see "side notes"
console.log(colorsJson.primaryBright);
```

Make sure to add these settings in the `compilerOptions` section of your `tsconfig.json` ([documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule)):

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

**Side notes:**

- Typescript 2.9.0 has a bug with this JSON feature, it was fixed with 2.9.2
- The esModuleInterop is only necessary for the default import of the colorsJson. If you leave it set to false then you have to import it with `import * as colorsJson from '../colors.json'`

Comment: You don't necessarily need `esModuleInterop`, but then you have to do `import * as foo from './foo.json';` -- the `esModuleInterop` was causing other problems for me when I tried enabling it.

Comment: You are right, I should have added that as a side note :-).

Comment: Note: Option "resolveJsonModule" cannot be specified without "node" module resolution strategy, so you also need to put `"moduleResolution": "node"` into your `tsconfig.json`. It also comes with the downside, that the `*.json` files you want to import need to be inside of `"rootDir"`. Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#json-imports

Comment: @mpen that's correct but `import * as foo from './foo.json'` is the wrong import form. It should be `import foo = require('./foo.json');` when not using `esModuleInterop`

Comment: Only part i needed was `"resolveJsonModule": true` and all is well

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer - You wrote: *"It also comes with the downside, that the *.json files you want to import need to be inside of "rootDir""* --- If that was in your link when you wrote the comment, it is gone now.  Instead the comment shows an example where the json file is not in the root directory.

Comment: I also needed "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true for TS 2.9.2

Comment: `import * as foo from './bar.json'` worked for me. TS 3.8

Comment: Using "resolveJsonModule": true is a correct setting. 
Somehow with my case, I use Visual Studio Code and it still show the error.  Luckily, I just closed and reopened the Visual Studio Code, the issue resolved.
So I suggest we should restart the IDE after changing tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 34):

Here's how to import a json file at runtime

```
import fs from 'fs'
var dataArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf-8'))
```

This way you avoid issues with tsc slowing down or running out of memory when importing large files, which can happen when using resolveJsonModule.

Comment: Yea but if its such a large file that it slows the compiler out of memory, you just called FS.readFileSync on that huge file, then you parsed it, synchronously. Don't you think it would be better to load it asynchronously? Given each situation is different, but as a generic answer to an issue I just don't see much benefit here.

Comment: Good point, but for some reason I had tsc crashing even for relatively small json files (< 1Mb, 20k lines), and reading&parsing the same file synchronously at runtime was not an issue. Not sure why that would be the case, I think tsc just doesn't handle compiling large arrays very well.

Answer (score 34):

In my case I needed to change **tsconfig.node.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [..., "colors.json"]
}
```

And to import like that:

```
import * as colors from './colors.json'
```

Or like that:

```
import colors from './colors.json'
```

with **"esModuleInterop": true**

Answer (score 18):

It's easy to use typescript version 2.9+. So you can easily import JSON files as [@kentor decribed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674344/159837).

But if you need to use older versions:

You can access JSON files in more TypeScript way. First, make sure your new `typings.d.ts` location is the same as with the `include` property in your `tsconfig.json` file.

If you don't have an include property in your `tsconfig.json` file. Then your folder structure should be like that:

```
- app.ts
+ node_modules/
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- typings.d.ts
```

But if you have an `include` property in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    },
    "exclude"        : [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*spec.ts"
    ], "include"        : [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Then your `typings.d.ts` should be in the `src` directory as described in `include` property

```
+ node_modules/
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- src/
    - app.ts
    - typings.d.ts
```

As In many of the response, You can define a global declaration for all your JSON files.

```ts
declare module '*.json' {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

but I prefer a more typed version of this. For instance, let's say you have configuration file `config.json` like that:

```json
{
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port"   : 8080
}
```

Then we can declare a specific type for it:

```ts
declare module 'config.json' {
    export const address: string;
    export const port: number;
}
```

It's easy to import in your typescript files:

```ts
import * as Config from 'config.json';

export class SomeClass {
    public someMethod: void {
        console.log(Config.address);
        console.log(Config.port);
    }
}
```

But in compilation phase, you should copy JSON files to your dist folder manually. I just add a script property to my `package.json` configuration:

```json
{
    "name"   : "some project",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc && cp src/config.json dist/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is rm -rf a Linux/Unix thing, or will that work on ol' Windurz also?

Comment: thank you, my typings.d.ts was out of place. As soon as I moved to /src the error message disappeared.

Comment: @Cody It's indeed only a Linux/Unix thing.

Answer (score 12):

In an Angular (typescript) app, I needed to include a `.json` file in my `environment.ts`. To do so, I had to set two options in tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Then, I could import my json file into the `environment.ts`:

```js
import { default as someObjectName } from "../some-json-file.json";
```

Answer (score 11):

You should add

```
"resolveJsonModule": true
```

as part of compilerOptions to tsconfig.json.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the code in the question is incorrect. The only thing you suggest is part of the several existing answers yet stripped of context.

Answer (score 9):

Often in Node.js applications a .json is needed. With TypeScript 2.9, --resolveJsonModule allows for importing, extracting types from and generating .json files.

Example #

```js
// tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}

// .ts

import settings from "./settings.json";

settings.debug === true;  // OK
settings.dry === 2;  // Error: Operator '===' cannot be applied boolean and number


// settings.json

{
    "repo": "TypeScript",
    "dry": false,
    "debug": false
}
```

by: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html

Comment: These are proper `compilerOptions` - work like a charm

Answer (score 9):

You can import a JSON file without modifying tsconfig by specifying explicitly that you are importing JSON

```
import mydata  from './mydataonfile.json' assert { type: "json" };
```

I know this does not fully answer the question but many people come here to know how to load JSON directly from a file.

Comment: Import assertions are only supported when the '--module' option is set to 'esnext' or 'nodenext'. ts(2821)

Answer (score 7):

Another way to go

```
const data: {[key: string]: any} = require('./data.json');
```

This was you still can define json type is you want and don't have to use wildcard.

For example, custom type json.

```
interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  birthday: Date;
}
const user: User = require('./user.json');
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question and is also bad practice.

Comment: I did this but I'm getting the dates as strings. What should I do to get the proper date objects deserialized from json?

Answer (score 4):

[TypeScript 5.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-3.html) introduced [Import Attributes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-3.html#import-attributes), formerly known as [Import Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#import-assertions), which can provide information about the expected format of an imported module at runtime.

Import Attributes ensure that a module is imported with the correct format. That means a `.json` file that actually contains runnable JavaScript code is definitely being interpreted as JSON.

```
import colors from "./colors.json" with { type: "json" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable `"resolveJsonModule": true` in `tsconfig.json` file and implement as below code, it's work for me:

```
const config = require('./config.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you using [@kentor ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript/50674344#50674344)

> Make sure to add these settings in the compilerOptions section of your tsconfig.json ([documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule)):

You need to add `--resolveJsonModule` and`--esModuleInterop` behind `tsc` command to compile your TypeScript file.

Example:
`tsc --resolveJsonModule --esModuleInterop main.ts`

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had to change: `"include": ["src"]` to `"include": ["."]` in addition to `"resolveJsonModule":true` because I tried to import `manifest.json` from the root of the project and not from `./src`

Answer (score 0):

`require` is a common way to load a JSON file in Node.js

Answer (score 0):

I tried all suggestions in this thread to-date, including setting resolveJsonModule to true, moduleResolution to "node", and various formats of the include statement (assert/with) and require. I also closed and restarted VSCode between most changes. Nothing here worked.

But from my ./src/index.ts, I did get `import metadata from './block.json` working and with no other errors, by setting the tsconfig.json `include` parameter to `["src"]`, and setting `"files":["src/block.json"]`. Note that the JSON file is not in the rootDir.

Interestingly (to me anyway) even when the './block.json' was getting the red squigglies, Intellisense on 'metadata' showed all of the properties defined in the JSON. I do not have a declaration of the schema in this project. So VSCode recognized the file and processed its contents even though TS flagged the error.

I don't know if this is version-specific. In this project I have TypeScript 5.3.3, @types/node 20.11.24, and the tsconfig.json below. From rootDir, my src folder has all source, processed by WebPack into ./build. (The reference to ./dist is there in case TypeScript needs a different outDir than WebPack.
I can't say this is **THE** solution for anyone else, or that other solutions might be more elegant for my own purposes or others, only that this configuration absolutely works as **A** solution for me at this moment.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "lib": ["ES2022", "ES2022.String", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "module": "ES2022",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "types": ["node"],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "files": ["src/block.json"]
}
```