# Importing static JSON in create-react-app + typescript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript

I am learning typescript and currently trying to import simple json file which I store locally in the project bootstrapped with create-react-app.

`data.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "test": "123",
}
```

In my `App.tsx` I am trying to import it using `json-loader`. Both `App.tsx` and `data.json` are in the same folder and the import looks like this:

```
import data from './data.json'
```

I've already tried couple solutions to this problem but nothing seems to work. Those solutions are `import * as data from './data.json'` and `const data = require('./data.json')`

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you eject the `create-react-app` configuration? You may need to share the portion of the webpack configuration where you added `json-loader`. You import statement looks right [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vgmnxn)

Comment: `var data = require('./data.json');` try this

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I did not eject, assumed that json-loader comes embedded in react-scripts. I get different error depending on what I try to do: in this case `import * as data from './data.json'` I can console.log the data BUT the error is `...containers/App.tsx(3,23): Cannot find module './data.json'`.

Comment: I assumed you ejected as you are using TypeScript. How are you integrating TypeScript with Webpack in your `create-react-app` project? You should probably share you configuration so others can help answer your issue.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Nothing fancy to share I suppose, I've just run `create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts` When I try to import like you did in your sandbox it gives me `Cannot find module` './data.json' error.

Comment: Check out this question regarding importing JSON in TypeScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript. It's not you, it's TypeScript.

Comment: `const data = require('./data.json')` this solution yields `require statement not part of an import statement` error

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I've already looked trough that answer but could not make much sense out of it, shall I create `typings.d.ts` and set it up corretly? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to import JSON you will likely have to try implementing what's in that answer. Otherwise you can just make it a `.js` file and export an object, which wouldn't require any additional configuration.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks again for taking your time

Comment: I wish I could have been more help, I'd keep the question open if I were you. There may be something simple to allow importing of JSON that I may be unaware of. Happy coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution 1: You can create a new file named data.json.ts with this statement:

```js
export default {your_json};
```

Then import:

```js
import { default as data } from './path/data.json';
```

ref: https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/issues/129

Solution 2: The problem here that when you compile your project (for example into a folder named lib) you don't have your .json file inside your lib folder. You simple can include that file into your build or manually copy that file into your lib folder.
To import your file you have to use:

- const data = require('data.json');
- declare your own type.
  Create a new file named **your_file_name.d.ts** and stick into this file the following code:

```json
declare module "*.json" 
{
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the import to: `import {test} from './data.json'`. This works for me.
If you want it named data you can change the name of `test` to `data` in the .JSON file. Or assign it to another variable after importing.