# Angular/Typescript - Wildcard module declaration

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7, angular-module

I'm trying to implement wildcard modules and i don't seem to get it work:

Right now i have the following code which works:

**typings.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as es from './i18n/es.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  hello = '-';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hello = es.default.hello;
  }
}
```

You may see a live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5nw8s), however i want to implement **WILDCARDS**, as seen [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) (typescriptlang) and [here](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2016/09/29/improving-typescript-modules/) (sitepen):
[image]

Implementation should allow me to do something like this:

**typings.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.json!i18n" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}

declare module "*.json!static" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}

declare module "*!text" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as es from './i18n/es.json!i18n';
import * as someObject from './static/someObject.json!static';
import * as template1 from './templates/template1.html!text';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  hello = '-';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hello = es.default.hello;
    console.log(someObject.default);
    console.log(template1.default);
  }
}
```

The issue is that for some reason wildcards are not being correctly recognized... throwing at runtime that "json" is not found.

- ***"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'json' in ..."***
- ***"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'static' in ..."***
- ***"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'text' in ..."***

An example of this feature working is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5787) when it was first implemented on Angular 2,

Any idea of what i'm doing wrong??

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because I discovered it is completely wrong: wildcard `declare module` does work for relative imports in TypeScript.  I think your problem is with the webpack configuration, but I don't know enough about that to help.

Comment: Thank you Matt, i thought so because i've tried to implement your answer without success :(

im still trying to figure out a way to implement this.

Comment: You shouldn't use `!` annotations in your imports. It should be extracted into webpack config.  
You might also want to check out `resolveJsonModule` flag

Comment: Hello @Ebuall, im already working without  `!` annotation, the reason for this question is that i want to implement it so i can make a separation of every different kind of JSON file, for example i18n JSON's module should look something simillar to this: `declare module "*.json!i18n" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
  export interface Language {
      [key: string]: any;
  };
}` i would be able encapsulate JSON behaviour/interfaces by just using the import.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320356/importing-static-json-in-create-react-app-typescript/52321611#52321611

Comment: @AironBrynchke please take a look to this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) at section **Wildcard module declarations**, according to the documentation the following import should work `import template1 from './templates/template1.html!text'`

Answer (score -1):

According to the [stackblitz code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5nw8s) you shared, 'static' and 'template' directories does not exists. Just create the directories and put your data in it. Also update your imports and remove `!i18n` or `!static` from paths.

```
import * as es from './i18n/es.json';
import * as someObject from './static/someObject.json';
```

I've tested with static/someObejcts only. Templates will also work in the same way.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as es from './i18n/es.json';
import * as someObject from './static/someObject.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  hello = '-';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hello = es.default.hello;
    console.log(es.default.hello);
    console.log(someObject.default.hello);

  }
}
```

**typings.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.json!i18n" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}

declare module "*.json!static" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

### stackblitz link

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klr6nb) is a working example of your code

Comment: Hello Javapocalypse,this question is about "how to use wildcards" so the goal is to get them working... wildcards are the "!static" and "!i18n" parts you suggested to use... removing them destroy the whole purpose of using them.

Comment: i've added a screenshoot showing the documentation of wildcards so you'll see what im actually trying to implement.