# Import JSON in Angular 7 project

Tags: json, angular, angular7

In my Angular project I'm importing JSON files for my own little localization service. I'm using [the method suggested here](https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79), updating my `typings.d.ts` to

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

This worked fine for Angular 6, but after the update to Angular 7 my imports seem to be undefined when I try to access a property.

```
import * as de from './strings/de.json';
import * as en from './strings/en.json';

var s = en["mykey"]
```

The JSON has a very simple key => value structure:

```
{
  "myKey": "My Headline",
  …
}
```

What has changed between 6.1 & 7 that could lead to this behaviour?

Comment: Can you share the `en.json` content format ?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: `en["mykey"]` is undefined but what about `en`, what's its value ?

Comment: Interestingly on closer inspection it seems that all values have been wrapped inside a new 'default'-object. 
Any ideas where this could be comming from?

Comment: Did you check the typescript version coming with Angular 7? Maybe there is something.

Comment: Angular 7 comes with typescript 3.1 : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes
didn't notice anything that would break imports from typescript 2.9 (Angular 6) to typescript 3.1

Comment: I feel like this part could be an indicator, although I don't really understand it completely  
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#under-allowsyntheticdefaultimports-types-for-default-imports-are-synthesized-less-often-for-ts-and-js-files

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Turns out with Angular 7 & TypeScript 3.1 [there actually have been some changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#under-allowsyntheticdefaultimports-types-for-default-imports-are-synthesized-less-often-for-ts-and-js-files) (I guess they have been there since TS 2.9+?). Using the code in the question, all values are wrapped inside a 'default'-object. To prevent this I had to simplify the import statements:

```
import de from './strings/de.json';
import en from './strings/en.json';
```

[Also see this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript) on how to import JSON files in TypeScript.

Comment: This was the explanation and solution I was looking for ^^^.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

After a lot of digging and trail and error, I finally got my app to import JSON correctly in Angular 7:

1. Firstly, **remove**

   ```
   "resolveJsonModule": true
   "esModuleInterop": true
   ```

   from *tsconfig.json*, if you have that in there from other non-Angular 7 specific answers.
2. Create *src/typings.d.ts*:

   ```
   declare module "*.json" {
     const value: any;
     export default value;
   }
   ```
3. Update `typeRoots` in *tsconfig.json* to use *src/typings.d.ts*, e.g:

   ```
   "typeRoots": [
     "node_modules/@types",
     "src/typings.d.ts"
   ],
   ```
4. Import JSON:

   ```
   import data from './data.json';
   console.log(data);
   ```

Comment: It should be noted that this is not necessary for importing into a component. It only seems necessary for importing into a service (or like entity?).

Answer (score 7):

In Angular 7 I had to take these steps:

(1) imports

```
import pkg from '../../package.json'
```

(2) tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    AND more compiler options here
  }
}
```

(3) angular.json (to stop ng lint breaking on JSON imports)

The only change here is to add ... `"**/*.json"`

```
"lint": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
  "options": {
    "tsConfig": [
      "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/*.json"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: using import * from * without  setting "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" to true in the tsconfig.json file would lead to errors, the above instruction as to go about is, however, valid, take note

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution that would work without me tinkering with the angular.json file

I solved it by exporting my JSON as a .ts constant:

```js
export const TEST_DATA = {...};
```

and then import it to my components