# require a json file results in an error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, visual-studio-code, checkjs

In a nodej project open in VsCode with `checkJs` enabled, when a json file is required like

```
const myFile = require('./my-file.json')
```

This makes an error `[ts] Cannot find module`.

**How is it possible to remove the error warning?**

I tried to:

1. add `"resolveJsonModule": true` to the `compilerOptions` in `jsconfig.json`, but it does not work.
2. create a `typing.d.ts` file with this content:

   `declare module '*.json' {
     const value: any;
     export default value;
   }`
   But now, there is an error `[ts] Type 'typeof import("*.json")' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. [2488]`

Comment: You don't need to specify json extension when you do a require. const myFile = require('./my-file');

Comment: Thanks but there is the same error if there is no extension. The error shows up because the json file is not a `module`. (-> it has no `module.exports`)

Comment: Check this answer, maybe that it can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar problem when trying to import json from a file in a typescript project.

I used

```
import * as data from "module/path/filename.json"
```

instead of

```
const data = require("module/path/filename.json")
```

and it worked.

Comment: This just gives me "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Answer (score 20):

You should add

`"resolveJsonModule":true`

as part of **compilerOptions** to tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had specified `outDir` and needed to put the json file at the output destination.