# angular 7 - importing a json file - compilation error

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors

A really nice feature of angular 7 is the support for typescript 3.1:

https://alligator.io/angular/angular-7/

I've Added the following 3 lines to the tsconfig.json file - under the 'compilerOptions' section:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

Everything looks good - i can iterate over my json file without a problem.

**But for some reason i'm getting a "TS2307: Cannot find module " error in my IDE:**

[image]

I've tried changing the import syntax to the suggestions in here:
[Importing json file in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript)

But without success.

Any ideas?

Edit: I use [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) as an IDE.

Comment: Did you ever get this worked out? I'm dealing with the same.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you didn't mention the IDE you were using but I use VSCode and what helped me was adding:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"annotateForClosureCompiler": false  
}
```

To `src/tsconfig.app.json`

And I no longer have importing issues, with my IDE with `.json` files. 
Pro tip, try:

```
import { default as awsData } from `....`
```

This will get rid of the import being added as a `default` property in the returned JSON object.

Comment: I use Webstorm - Edited my question.

Comment: Not sure how this helps as default is `false` already: https://v7.angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#annotateforclosurecompiler

Answer (score -2):

Restarting the IDE after setting `"resolveJsonModule": true` should work.