# Ionic read local JSON file

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to read a local JSON file in Ionic 3. I have saved the JSON file in assets folder as csvjson.json

I call the following function inside one of the services.

getProducts() {
    console.log('Inside getProducts')

```
return this.http.get(this.apiHost)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
  });
```

}

and then store the result in

```
myArray = this.databaseprovider.getProducts();
console.log("Returned from getProducts:" + myArray.length);
```

However I get the output as

> Returned from getProducts:undefined

Can you pls suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: from the above code not getting that what exactly you are doing explain it more

Comment: In the http.get one does not need to call map anymore as it returns a json already. Thus I used the code below.   `this.http.get<any[]>('assets/csvjson.json')
                .subscribe(data => {
                  data.forEach((item) => {
                    console.log(item);
                    console.log(item.Category);`

Answer (score 2):

Put the <**file-name**>.json file in assets folder and change the request to following,

```
public getProducts() { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._http.get("assets/<file-name>.json")
            .map((response: Response) => {
                console.log(response);
                resolve(response.json());
        });
    });
}
```

> Component file

```
this.databaseprovider.getProducts().then((result)=>{
   myArray = result;
});
console.log("Returned from getProducts:" + myArray.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use **fetch()** function like that:

````
    readJsonData(){    
            fetch("../../assets/data/Parameters.json").then(res=>res.json()).then(json=>{
                console.log("OUTPUT: ", json);
                //DO YOUR STAFF
            });
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

When you call it in your Typescript File of your Page for example called `yourPage.ts` in the `yourPage` folder you can access the local JSON File by **importing** it:

**yourPage.ts**:

```
import * as JSONdata from "../../assets/csvjson.json" //You can name 'JSONdata' as you want
```

To call it:

```
getProducts() {
 console.log(JSONdata);
}
```

Comment: You may need to modify your typescript configuration to use this solution, see:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

> import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

this.http.get("assets.data.json").subscribe((data:any)=>{
  console.log(data);
});
```