# Importing json file in typescript 2.9.2 and Angular 6 app is not working

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am running an Angular 6 app, with this version of typescript: `"typescript": "~2.9.2"`

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674344/5100278) to import json files in typescript 2.9.*, but it's not working.

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

And then my `app.component.ts` file where I'm importing it:

```
import * as config from '../../config.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
error TS2497: Module '"C:/Users/..../config"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular, but did you try `import config from '../../config.json';` ?

Comment: @Striped Now I'm getting: `...has no default export`

Comment: I see this, could it help ? https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-read-local-json-files-in-angular/

Comment: There is a diffenrence, the `"esModuleInterop": true` within the tsconfig.json file which allow default imports from modules with no default export.

Answer (score 4):

I used `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to make this work and `import version from './package.json'`.
According to the docs synthetic imports allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. Using this, I no longer had the error you mentioned.