# Cannot find module on import with local JSON file

Tags: json, angular

I have this simple angular project and I'm having trouble importing a local json file that I created. Here's the JSON file:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Uziel",
    "lastName": "Cabanban",
    "car" : {
        "brand": "Toyota",
        "model": "Vios",
        "year": 2017
    }
}
```

The JSON file is stored in this directory: `src/assets/sampleJson.json`.

Here is my component that tries to import said json file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import SampleJson from '../assets/sampleJson.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

I haven't written anything yet as I'm getting a red line in the `import SampleJson from '../assets/sampleJson.json`

Any suggestion will be much appreciated

Comment: Will you write out the path of your app.component.ts file?

Perhaps the relative path '../assets/' is not a legal relative path.

Comment: `app.component.ts` is in `/src/app/app.component.ts` while the json file is in `/src/assests/sampleJson.json`. The `assets` folder was automatically generated when I generated the angular project. I didn't manually create it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for all of the suggestions but I went another direction and didn't use `import` anymore. Instead I used `require` and I used it like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { user } from './user.model';

declare var require: any;

var myUser: user = require('../assests/sampleJson.json');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor () {
    console.log(myUser);
  }
}
```

So far it prints the contents of my json file

Answer (score 8):

`.json` file is not a TypeScript module. Since you want **local** file (assuming it is hardcoded), you can do it by creating a `.ts` file and `export` a constant/variable from it like following:

**sampleJson.ts**

```
export const SampleJson = {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Uziel",
    "lastName": "Cabanban",
    "car" : {
        "brand": "Toyota",
        "model": "Vios",
        "year": 2017
    }
}
```

Then in the component:

```
import SampleJson from '../assets/sampleJson';  // path can change
```

Hope this helps

---

More on TypeScript Modules: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

---

**Update**

Or you can import a JSON file using

`import * as SampleJSON from 'path/to/json/sampleJson.json`

with TypeScript v2.9.+ according to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674344/1331040