# unable to import JSON in typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I have a json file which looks like this

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "blele",
    "private_key_id": "9c0a8fe58c6a35a1640677b7dbf5b",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCQAsmXWkbeNsLn\nktPmTGONatPlZevmvSDO0IIMymUuRHPOuTQRm6k6WkYB1BB5gulGOsOc10hGrscK\nJtxj/G+eZguTvybosKdwVbm5sZ1jCUlS/TdmAVtJVWGf1YT/nxS1RuT+d7obFGN3\nNhMzQ2sm6JwmPIfF7kcfcU9Cjgjj5mDMa7OO2PQ4/gkKi+8/HhMge/4Wde\nd+/htb6ZA6BdHFSoevHHgTkkygJF47oDeirSN5VDDc1FYqSSZnCZ45uRik3RsAcw\ndInRhknSKdcbqyug9FQgM6l9T8a0sMpwgVcAjq3WaJaUgO1Wd9nfMhoItZvc6cIc\nbbBl3FxRAgMBAAECggEACK2gNQBGsRBfR0hdE/Y0oWnlJg8tSdM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\n+QRKKqMNCLQnNmn3UYNLm6LXoc9t2gdIphBMLxL2L3zx+3IIvXl4\ntDD81zZNMkErG9wyyNrgxtgl8RZQcu4mggyrRu/CMh\nAU4EdEzxmT3jtAg28bGUys1ZINw0OY2Tlr4wZzW/iaIIK34VvtsByrNJ1G4nKlnS\n6xIYt5gv7buhMI/E8MBcf5EOThegr0kS/GYTd2H5u/Oj+gE33+V5C9qdk84v2Hn6\n1dUqBNjWjtlbRXjxFv4UAQ4=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-0fcdc@be.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "10713329946488",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-0fc.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

in `./.keys/admin.keys.json`

I want to import that file in index.ts.

When I did something like this

```
import firebaseKeys from './.keys/admin.keys.json'
```

it is giving me an error (red underline on the vscode saying

> Module
>   '"/Users/aia/Desktop/ble-typescript/functions/src/.keys/admin.keys"'
>   can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flagts(1259)
>   admin.keys.json(1, 1): This module is declared with using 'export =',
>   and can only be used with a default import when using the
>   'esModuleInterop' flag.

this how my tsconfig looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

This is my first project so can someone help me in comprehending how i can use .json file in typescript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing json file in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `"esModuleInterop": true` under `"compilerOptions"` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ..
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  ..
}
```

Form more information on compiler options, see the [compiler options documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).