# How to remove mysterious "default" field added to JSON?

Tags: json, typescript

I have the following `jsondata.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "car": "ferrari"
}
```

In the same directory, I have a typescript file `main.ts` where I simply `congole.log` the json from the `jsondata.json`

```
import * as j from './jsondata.json';

console.log(j);
```

The result is surprising:

```
{
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  car: 'ferrari',
  default: { name: 'John', age: 30, car: 'ferrari' }
}
```

What is that **`default`** field? Why does it appear, and how can I get rid of it?

---

For reference, this is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./out",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997144/941240

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried some combinations of the settings and found that the last two settings are the required behavior.

jsondata.json:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "car": "ferrari2"
}
```

---

#### resolveJsonModule set to true and no esModuleInterop and import with no * import causes error.

main.ts:

```
import j from './jsondata.json';
console.log(j);
```

tsconfig.ts:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
// "esModuleInterop": true
```

result:

```
>

{ name: 'John', age: 30, car: 'ferrari2' }

Module ... can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag
```

---

#### Both flags are set to true and * import shows default

main.ts:

```
import * as j from './jsondata.json';
console.log(j);
```

tsconfig.ts

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

result:

```
>

{
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  car: 'ferrari2',
  default: { name: 'John', age: 30, car: 'ferrari2' }
}
```

---

#### Both flags set to true with no * import does not show default

main.ts:

```
import j from './jsondata.json';
console.log(j);
```

tsconfig.ts:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

result:

```
>

{ name: 'John', age: 30, car: 'ferrari2' }
```

---

#### resolveJsonModule set too true and no esModuleInterop and * import shows no default

main.ts:

```
import * as j from './jsondata.json';
console.log(j);
```

tsconfig.ts:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
// "esModuleInterop": true
```

result:

```
>

{ name: 'John', age: 30, car: 'ferrari2' }
```

---

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript) for a way to do this using types in typescript. The fact to declare a generic json module in typings.d.ts removes the `default` property from the imported json file.