# Importing JSON as a type

Tags: typescript

How do I define the type for imported json? For example

```
{
  "things": "foo"
}
```

```
interface Data {
  things: String,
  another?: String
}
```

```
import data from './data.json' // Should have type Data
console.log(data.things)
console.log(data.another) // Should be allowed but undefined
```

The `resolveJsonModule` option will automatically generate types for the imported JSON but it is incomplete as the JSON may not contain all the possible fields for the data.

How do I define the type myself?

Comment: Could you elaborate on _it isn't permissive enough_?

Comment: You can use path mapping to specify a different type for that JSON

Comment: @AluanHaddad How does path mapping help?

Comment: Well, you can create a file like `./data.json.d.ts` containing `declare const data: Data; export default data;` then you can set a paths entry `"*/data.json": ["data.json"]` which would work for a non-relative import like `import data from "app/data.json"`. On the other hand, isn't that needs to be relative you can skip paths mapping and just put that `data.json.d.ts` file right beside your `data.json` JSON file

Answer (score 23):

I can think of 3 main ways here:

1. You can use a `require` with a type assertion like so:

```js
const data: Data = require('./data.json')
```

2. You can continue to `import`, but use an additional variable (typed) like so:

```js
import untypedData from './data.json'

const data: Data = untypedData
```

3. You can add a module typings file and add this to the `typeRoots` part of your `tsconfig.json` like so:

```js
// File data.d.ts
declare module "data.json" {
  things: String,
  another?: String
}
```

```json
// File tsconfig.json
{
  ...
  "typeRoots": [
    "/*path to data.d.ts*/"
  ]
}
```

This will let you `import` along with having the imported item typed correctly

See also
[Importing json file in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript)

Comment: I can't use require.

Comment: @RedHatter are you able to elaborate on what prevents you from being able to use a `require` statement?

Comment: It is not supported in the environment I'm using.

Comment: Updated with a few other options @RedHatter

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having an intermediate variable, you can do it this way:

```
import _data from './data.json';
const data: Data = _data;
```

The `_data` variable is of whatever type the compiler infers for it, while the `data` variable has the same value but is of the type you annotate.

[Codesandbox link to code](https://codesandbox.io/s/65775338-4hm7c?file=/index.ts)

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. I would really a cleaner way that doesn't require an intermediate variable.

Comment: I couldn't figure out any such cleaner way using `import` syntax.  You can do something like `const data2: Data = await import('./data.json');` using [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports), but has so many caveats (slower, asynchronous, makes babies cry, etc) that I wouldn't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022;**

First, enable related option in `tsconfig.json` file, like:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {

        ...

        "resolveJsonModule": true,
    }
}
```

Then simply `import`, and use `typeof` keyword, like:

```
import myJsonObject from './my-file.json';

export type MyType = typeof myJsonObject;
```

> **Note** that you don't need to define and export type, and could instead directly use as type, like:
>
> ```
> let myVariable: typeof myJsonObject;
> ```