# How to import a json file in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a json file say data.json,

```
[
   {
       "page" : "First" ,
       "subpage" : "FirstA",
       "title" : [
           {
               "one" : "Heading 1",
               "two" : "Heading 2"
           }
       ]
   },...
]
```

How do I import this in my "tsx" file?

```
import data './location';
```

Seems to throw the error :

```
{
    "message": "Cannot find module 'location' or its corresponding type declarations."
}
```

In my tsconfig.json I have added,

```
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,...
```

along with the other configarations..

Any idea on what I may be missing??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript/49997144

Comment: FYI the linked question are a bit older so some of those steps aren't necessary anymore.  `"resolveJsonModule": true` should do it.  Does `import data from './location';` work?

Comment: @LindaPaiste , import data from './location'; worked