# Read local JSON file in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, reader

How can I read a locally stored JSON file into a variable in typescript? I have a json file of photos that looks like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "camera": "",
      "location": "",
      "iso": 0,
      "aperture": 0,
      "focal length": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "camera": "",
      "location": "",
      "iso": 0,
      "aperture": 0,
      "focal length": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "camera": "",
      "location": "",
      "iso": 0,
      "aperture": 0,
      "focal length": 0
    }
]
```

I'm trying to read the file as text and then use `Json.Parse` but how do I read it as text in the first place? I've tried using FileReader.readAsText but it only accepts blob objects. Do I need to create a blob object from my filepath or is there a easier way to read local JSON files?

Comment: what do you mean by locally stored ? is it on your machine or in codebase ?

Comment: A simple import should do it

Comment: It's stored in the codebase

Comment: @Liad I've tried import photos from "./assets/photos.json" but it says it cant find the module

Comment: In the codebase and bundled with the code, right?

Comment: @CameronCheung   check my answer with example : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67841905/8175467

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing JSON file in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it but need to modify `tsconfig.json`.
In `tsconfig.json` there is a setting called `resolveJsonModule`. By default its value is set to `false`.

TL;DR

1. Open `tsconfig.json` and if `resolveJsonModule` is not present in the `compilerOptions` then add it as below:

   ```js
   "resolveJsonModule": true,
   ```
2. Open the component where you want to read the file and import like:

   ```js
   import * as photos from '../../path-to file';
   ```

the above changes are sufficient to import the file.
Here is the example : [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aakied?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can import the json file

```
import all from '../../path/to/file.json'
```

then declare like below for typing

```
const samples = (all as DataType)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't expect the file to change, you can use `require('path')` to get it. It should just return the object; no need to JSON.parse.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your tsconfig

```
compilerOptions: { ... 
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
}
```

And then import it like any module

```
import myfile from './path/to/json/file.json';
```