# How to store JSON values in an object costructor in TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

**EDIT OF MY QUESTION**

I have a json file named products.json which contains a list of products with their id, name, quantity, description and url of images relating to this product.
Example of the JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name": "APPLE IPHONE 13 256GO",
    "desc": "some desc ...",
    "price": 1599.0,
    "qty": 15,
    "imgUrls": "../Images/iphone-13"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name": "GALAXY NOTE10",
    "desc": "some desc ...",
    "price": 200.0,
    "qty": 10,
    "imgUrls": "../Images/galaxy"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name": "APPLE IPHONE 12 128GO",
    "desc": "some desc ...",
    "price": 1599.0,
    "qty": 15,
    "imgUrls": "../Images/iphone-12"
  }
]
```

Also, I have the Product object below:

```
export class Product {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public desc: string,
    public price: number,
    public qty: number,
    public imgUrls: string[]
  ) {}
}
```

I want to create an array of type Product, which contains all my products imported from the json file.

I know that by adding the products manually it will be like this.

```
products: Product[] = [
new Product(1,
            "APPLE IPHONE 13 256GO",
            "some desc...",
            1599.0,
            15,
            ["../Images/iphone-13"]),
new Product(2,
            "GALAXY NOTE10",
            "some desc...",
            200.0,
            10,
            ["../Images/galaxy"]),
new Product(3,
            "APPLE IPHONE 12 128GO",
            "some desc ...",
            1599.0,
            15,
            ["../Images/iphone-12"])
];
```

but i want to create this object using the json file.

Thank you so much for yur help.

Sorry if i m not clear, you can mention that in comments so i can edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

This works, just make sure the names match

```js
export class Product {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public nom: string,
    public description: string,
    public prix: number,
    public quantite: number,
    public photo: string
  ) {}
}

const products:Array<Product> = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "nom": "APPLE IPHONE 13 256GO",
    "description": "some desc ...",
    "prix": 1599.0,
    "quantite": 15,
    "photo": "../Images/iphone-13"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "nom": "GALAXY NOTE10",
    "description": "some desc ...",
    "prix": 200.0,
    "quantite": 10,
    "photo": "../Images/galaxy"
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "nom": "APPLE IPHONE 12 128GO",
    "description": "some desc ...",
    "prix": 1599.0,
    "quantite": 15,
    "photo": "../Images/iphone-12"
  }
];
```

Comment: the data come from a JSON file, and then i need to convert it to an array of Product object.

Comment: `import` it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674344/236465

Answer (score 0):

First read the file from the filesystem and parse it (or alternatively `import` it). Then map over the array and create and instance of `Product` for each object in the array. As your `imgUrl` is an array of strings you will have to check whether the input is an array or not and possibly wrap a single value in the array.

```js
import { readFile } from "fs/promises";

interface IValue {
  id: number;
  nom: string;
  description: string;
  prix: number;
  quantité: number;
  photo: string;
}

async function getValues(): Promise<Array<IValue>> {
  // read file from filesystem
  // TODO: error handling
  const valuesRaw = await readFile("./values.json", { encoding: "utf-8" });
  return JSON.parse(valuesRaw);
}

class Product {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public desc: string;
  public price: number;
  public qty: number;
  public imgUrls: string[];

  constructor(
    id: number,
    name: string,
    desc: string,
    price: number,
    qty: number,
    imgUrls: string[]
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.price = price;
    this.qty = qty;
    this.imgUrls = imgUrls;
  }
}

(async () => {
  const values = await getValues();
  const result: Product[] = values.map(
    (prod) =>
      new Product(
        prod.id,
        prod.nom,
        prod.description,
        prod.prix,
        prod.quantité,
        // check wether data is an array and if it's not put the single value in an array
        Array.isArray(prod.photo) ? prod.photo : [prod.photo]
      )
  );
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Expected output:

```
[
  Product {
    id: 1,
    name: 'APPLE IPHONE 13 256GO',
    desc: 'some desc ...',
    price: 1599,
    qty: 15,
    imgUrls: [ '../Images/iphone-13' ]
  },
  Product {
    id: 2,
    name: 'GALAXY NOTE10',
    desc: 'some desc ...',
    price: 200,
    qty: 10,
    imgUrls: [ '../Images/galaxy' ]
  },
  Product {
    id: 3,
    name: 'APPLE IPHONE 12 128GO',
    desc: 'some desc ...',
    price: 1599,
    qty: 15,
    imgUrls: [ '../Images/iphone-12' ]
  }
]
```

Comment: hi, can you review my question i edit it, please. Thanks

Comment: I did, and I think I have answered your question already. I am reading the values from a `.json` file, parse it to have it available in JS and then create a Product instance for each of the products in the file. Maybe I am missing something, but doesn't my answer answer your question? Where's the problem? What's missing/ not working?