# Cannot find module when trying to import from a JSON file in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, cypress

We are migrating from JS to TypeScript for our Cypress Project. I am getting the error message from my **Login.ts**:

```
Cannot find module '../../fixtures/users/user' or its corresponding type declarations.
Cannot find module '../../fixtures/users/admin' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Login.ts content:

```js
import user from "../../fixtures/users/user"
import admin from "../../fixtures/users/admin"

class Login {
        // Some code
}
```

Our folder tree is as follows:

[image]

The content of *admin* and *user.json* are just simple identical values:

```json
{
    "val": {
        "firstname": "Alex",
        "lastname": "Shepherd"
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything here?

EDIT:

I saw this [thread comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674344/6029971) that seems to work for this JSON importing situation. I'm not sure though if this is the optimal way to do this. I added the below lines in my **tsconfig.json**:

```json
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

Also, I added the extension in my import calls:

```js
import user from "../../fixtures/users/user.json"
import admin from "../../fixtures/users/admin.json"
```

Comment: maybe you need to use extension `.json` and since it's `json` you need to use `assert { type: "json" }` if nodejs version is higher than 17+

Comment: where would I put that `assert { type: "json" }` part?

Comment: `import user from "../../fixtures/users/user.json" assert { type: "json" };` same for `admin`

Comment: I did it the same way. But I still get the `Cannot find module '../../fixtures/users/user' or its corresponding type declarations.` error. Also I have to mention that upon adding the assert part, this error message appeared `Import assertions are only supported when the '--module' option is set to 'esnext' or 'nodenext'.`

Comment: i just seen now that path is wrong try `import user from '../fixtures/users/user.json';`
`../../` this is wrong path

Comment: Tried the `../` option and the error path updated as well `Cannot find module '../fixtures/users/user' or its corresponding type declarations.`