# ".filter is not a function" on Imported JSON with Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I'm in the process of upgrading my vanilla JS code to Typescript. In my file I'm importing a JSON file, then using `.filter()` to get just the items that are in stock. I've already added `"resolveJsonModule": true` to my `tsconfig.json` file and updated my import statement syntax [[Reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996456/importing-json-file-in-typescript).

```
// products.json

[
    { "category": "Fruits", "price": 1.00, "stocked": true, "name": "Apple" },
    { "category": "Fruits", "price": 1.00, "stocked": true, "name": "Dragonfruit" },
    { "category": "Fruits", "price": 2.00, "stocked": false, "name": "Passionfruit" }
]
```

```
// app.ts

interface ProductProps {
    name: string;
    category: string;
    stocked: boolean;
    price: number;
}

import * as productData from './data/products.json';

const stockedItems: ProductProps[] = filterStocked(productData);

function filterStocked(products: ProductProps[]) {
    return products.filter(product => product.stocked);
}
```

But when I compile the code and run it in the browser I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: products.filter is not a function

This didn't happen before I started using Typescript, the function filtered the products perfectly. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import a JSON file you're not actually getting a plain-ol' array, but an Object that stores a bunch of extra info about the data that was imported. You can see this by typing `console.log(productData)`:

[image: browser console message showing a javascript Object with sub-arrays and a Prototype instance]

But when you go to use an array-only method like `filter()` on the the returned data, Javascript assumes what you're trying to do and executes the method as if it were just a normal array; so no errors, everything runs fine, easy-peasy (it's probably more technical than that but let's just keep it simple for the purposes of this answer).

But Typescript? Well, Typescript doesn't assume *anything* — that's kind of the whole point of Typescript. It sees that JSON import for exactly what it is — an Object — and you can't use `filter()` on an Object, so it throws an error.

The solution is to explicitly convert the returned JSON data to an array using `Array.from()`:

```
import * as productData from './data/products.json';
const products = Array.from(productData);

const stockedItems: ProductProps[] = filterStocked(products);
```

Now you've got an actual array that you can use `filter()` on, and Typescript doesn't get mad because everything is typed the way it's supposed to be.